# React; Why does my array.map method render only one element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to render a component multiple times based on an array passed on from the parent component. But the child component gets whole array as property so does not render correctly. Can I get any tips on that?

```
App.js
function App() {
  const [businesses, setBusinesses] = useState([]);

  function searchYelp(term, location) {
    Yelp.search(term, location)
      .then((businessesList) => {
        setBusinesses([businessesList]); // this should be updated to setBusinesses(businessesList)
      })
      .then(console.log(businesses));
  }

  console.log(businesses);
  return (
    <div>
      <Hero>
        <SearchBar searchYelp={searchYelp} />
      </Hero>
      <Layout>
        <BusinessList businesses={businesses} />
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

BusinessList.js    
const BusinessList = ({ businesses }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 className="business-list__header">İşletmeler</h2>
          <div className="business-list">
            {businesses.map((business) => {
              return <Business business={business} key={business.id} />;
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

Business.js

const Business = ({ business }) => {
  return (
    <div className="business">
      <div className="business__image-container">
        <img src={business.imageSrc} alt="İşletme Görseli" />
      </div>

      <div className="business__information">
        <h2 className="business__header">{business.name}</h2>
        <div className="business__address">
          <p className="business__address-text">{business.address}</p>
          <p className="business__address-text">{business.city}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="business__reviews">
          <h3 className="business__reviews-header">{business.category}</h3>
          <h3 className="business__rating">{business.rating}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

You can see the values components get below.

[Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTLWB.png)
[Extended Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5NbG.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem and share your data structure.

Comment: Have you checked the length of your array to make sure that it has more than one element?

Comment: I have added a screenshot for the data that Business component receives. It gets an array based on search bar. The values get passed from parent. I want to get and array of Objects to render multiple instances of Business component.

Comment: It seems that Business receives a list of business, but you expect the list in businesses inside BusinessList. So, it seems that businesses is a list composed by one element that contains a list of business. What is the output if you console.log businesses?

Comment: Can you show the parent component for BusinessList?

Comment: can you give a screenshot of businesses json. Might be only one element in bussiness. try map function by changing to businesses[0].map

Comment: Yes, I get the list in BusinessList, but when I map on the array to try to pass on the individual values, Business component get it as the same as parent component.

Comment: In BusinessList add a first line `console.log(JSON.stringify(businesses))`

Comment: Can you expand the `businesses` prop in the parent? So, we can clearly see what you have there. Probably you have an array of objects, and again for each object an array of objects.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot for BusinessList Component.

Comment: When I stringiyfy businesses I get: [[{"id":"qMQ_pZnOfamB2lI2-0oibQ","imageSrc":"https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/oxKj7QzJdb8o-Pp5vvRthQ/o.jpg","name":"Makarna Sarayı","address":"Molla Fenari Mahallesi  Vezirhan Caddesi","city":"Fatih","state":"34","zipCode":"34216","category":"Turkish","rating":4.5,"reviewCount":7},...etc]

Comment: Well, I use Yelp api to get businesses, so I dont have a businesses.json, but when I try to map businesses[0].map it crashes instantly since it has no values at the beginning.

Comment: So, as we can see you are mapping the data in the parent but each `businness` is actually an array again. So, I don't know how are you going to display that data but if you make another `map` in the child, you can display individual items.

Comment: Well after stringifying the businesses I noticed that my output is structured like that: [[ {business data} ]] So it is not an array of objects, it is an array of objects inside and array. So I need to get rid of the outside array I guess...

Comment: Hey Mates, Thanks to all of your help, I got it to work. I will update the question. I am very glad that we have such an active and great community. Regards. Take care of yourselves.

Comment: In the future please post text, not links to images of text. You can get data logged by using `JSON.stringify(theData, null, 2)` nicely formatted.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thank you very much, I will keep this in mind!